# Export data to Excel from a dashboard

Tags: datazen-server

Is it possible to allow end users to export data to Excel from a dashboard. I see that the functionality exists within Datazen Publisher when in "Data View" but that doesn't accommodate end users.

Comment: This question sounds like it might be more appropriate for [superuser.se], since it's not related to programming. If you do choose to ask this there, please let me know and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to export the data that end users see in Datazen to Excel. The features are stated in http://www.datazen.com/features/#connections and all you can do with Excel is read data. I really hope they add this feature.